# magento is not picking Locale

Tags: localisation

I am getting error in log. error is

> The language 'nb_NO' has to be added before it can be used. in
>   /public_html/lib/Zend/Translate/Adapter.php on line 430

Translations for nb_NO are not working.

Please let me know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It means that Zend does not recognize the language. Check `lib/Zend/Locale.php` if it contains `nb_NO` and if not, add it.

Optionally debug the zend class `lib/Zend/Translate/Adapter.php` to see what it is looking for and what is available.

As far as I can see it should be available and if you have created a language pack in Magento for the locale it should work.